# Sidebar Padding/Align

Tags: home-page-component, sidebar

I've added to the classic sidebar a custom homepage component (orange/green) (see screentshot), but it doesnt fit with standard components (blue), how can I adjust this view.

[image: Sidbar Classic]

Comment: Did you try to remove the padding and margin on your custom component using `* { padding: 0; margin: 0; } `?

Comment: now it works, I've set the sidebar and the header to false.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out on your own. Please post your solution as answer on this question, so you can mark it as solved for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. You need to set the `sidebar` and `header` attributes inside of the visualforce's `page` tag to `false`.